# How to convert Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> to Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Hi I have an API returning `Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>`, the API will call another API which returns `Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>>`, how do I convert the result from this other API to `Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>`? e.g.

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> api() {
    return anotherApi()
        .map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().build())
        .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.badRequest().build());
}
```

The above works if I only have the `map`, but not when I add the `onErrorReturn`, it complains `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> to Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>>`, why has it become `Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is correct and this is just Java generics that couldn't infer type correctly.

You could provide type explicitly

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> api() {
    return anotherApi()
        .<ResponseEntity<Void>>map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().build())
        .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.badRequest().build());
}
```

or move `onErrorReturn` one level up

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> api() {
    return anotherApi()
        .onErrorReturn(ResponseEntity.badRequest().build())
        .map(response -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
}
```

Comment: Interesting! Moving it up solved it, wonder why, but thanks!